# $rootScope is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use a cookie value in multiple places and within multiple controllers but I get error saying **$rootScope is not defined**

Here's the code:

```
capApp.controller('cookieCtrl', ['$scope','$cookies', function($scope, $rootScope, $cookies) {
  // set variable for nav
  $rootScope.cookieSet = $cookies.user_id;
}]);

capApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location) {  
  $scope.user_id = $rootScope.cookieSet; // set global var
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? Basically I want the cookie value available site wide

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You missed to add `$rootScope` dependency in **both controllers**

**Code**

```
capApp.controller('cookieCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', '$cookies', 
  function($scope, $rootScope, $cookies) {
  // set variable for nav
  $rootScope.cookieSet = $cookies.user_id;
}]);

capApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 
  function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {  
  $scope.user_id = $rootScope.cookieSet; // set global var
});
```

Ensure [**array annotation of dependency injection**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to ensure it won't break the code while doing JavaScript minification.

> Side Note:- Don't use `$rootScope` for sharing application common function / data, do use service/factory for the same

Comment: Side note side note: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq "[..] don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data"

Answer (score 4):

You didn't inject $rootScope in mainController

```
capApp.controller('mainController', function($scope,$rootScope, $location) {  
  $scope.user_id = $rootScope.cookieSet; // set global var
});
```

**Update:**

First create a service that acts like a bridge between controllers:

1) addCookie  used to add cookieset.

2) getCookie  used to get cookieset.

```
capApp.factory('user', function() {
  var cookieSet;

  var addCookie = function(val) {
      cookieSet=val;
  }

  var getCookie = function(){
      return cookieSet;
  }

  return {
    addCookie : addCookie,
    getCookie : getCookie 
  };

});

capApp.controller('cookieCtrl', ['$scope', 'user', '$cookies', function($scope, user, $cookies) {
  // set variable for nav
  user.addCookie($cookies.user_id);
}]);

capApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location,user) {  
  $scope.user_id =user.getCookie(); // set global var
});
```

Comment: why you are mixing up service syntax with factory, you should use `this` instead of local `var` while using service, & shouldn't return object, do look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473

Comment: Personally I like your service approach +1 for it :)